# htaccess rewrite condition to a php file in WP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this htaccess file in the '*public_html*' folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ asset.php?code=$1 [NC]
```

Essentially, the rewrite condition should work as follows. When a user clicks on a link *../asset/XXX*, the `asset.php` file generates a new webpage containing details of the *XXX* asset.

The lookup is not working as I think the *htaccess* file cannot find the '`asset.php`' file.

The asset.php file is located in

*'public_html/wp-content/themes/theme1/asset.php'*

How can I modify the htaccess file to lookup this file?

Comment: Presumably by changing the redirect part of the rule to `public_html/wp-content/themes/theme1/asset.php?code=$1`

Comment: If you have more than only these 2 lines in your .htaccess File - you maybe have to use the L Flag to stop further processing. Eg: ...$1 [L,NC]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

`RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ wp-content/themes/theme1/asset.php?code=$1 [NC]`

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite is from your directory where the htaccess file is located. So add the path to the destination file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ wp-content/themes/theme1/asset.php?code=$1 [NC]
```

Perhaps you can set the RewriteBase to `/`. Sometimes that fixes some problems.

Comment: I get the following message: is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500